# Spring 4 Not Binding JSon to POJO

Tags: spring, rest, web-services, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a RestFul dao web service.  Very simply call the make a HTTP request CRUD data.  All seems to be working (I am using curl to create HTTP request) except that in the controller method I am not getting json data bound to a pojo.  This is the controller code:

```
@PostMapping("/deleteJonTblGet")
public ResponseEntity getDeleteJonTbl(@RequestBody DeleteJonTblId deleteJonTblId)
{
    System.out.println("TEST:");
    System.out.println(deleteJonTblId.getDJon());

    DeleteJonTbl deleteJonTbl = deleteJobTblDao.findById(1);
    if (deleteJonTbl == null)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity("No Customer found for ID ", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity(deleteJonTbl, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Here is the POJO:
public class DeleteJonTblId implements java.io.Serializable
{

```
private String DJon;
private String DReturn;
private Integer DCtr;
private String DRecdat;
private String DRectime;

public DeleteJonTblId()
{
}

public DeleteJonTblId(String DJon, String DReturn, Integer DCtr, String DRecdat, String DRectime)
{
    this.DJon = DJon;
    this.DReturn = DReturn;
    this.DCtr = DCtr;
    this.DRecdat = DRecdat;
    this.DRectime = DRectime;
}

@Column(name = "D_JON", length = 12)
public String getDJon()
{
    return this.DJon;
}

public void setDJon(String DJon)
{
    this.DJon = DJon;
}

@Column(name = "D_RETURN", length = 2)
public String getDReturn()
{
    return this.DReturn;
}

public void setDReturn(String DReturn)
{
    this.DReturn = DReturn;
}

@Column(name = "D_CTR", precision = 7, scale = 0)
public Integer getDCtr()
{
    return this.DCtr;
}

public void setDCtr(Integer DCtr)
{
    this.DCtr = DCtr;
}

@Column(name = "D_RECDAT", length = 8)
public String getDRecdat()
{
    return this.DRecdat;
}

public void setDRecdat(String DRecdat)
{
    this.DRecdat = DRecdat;
}

@Column(name = "D_RECTIME", length = 6)
public String getDRectime()
{
    return this.DRectime;
}

public void setDRectime(String DRectime)
{
    this.DRectime = DRectime;
}

public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    if ((this == other))
        return true;
    if ((other == null))
        return false;
    if (!(other instanceof DeleteJonTblId))
        return false;
    DeleteJonTblId castOther = (DeleteJonTblId) other;

    return ((this.getDJon() == castOther.getDJon())
        || (this.getDJon() != null && castOther.getDJon() != null && this.getDJon().equals(castOther.getDJon())))
        && ((this.getDReturn() == castOther.getDReturn()) || (this.getDReturn() != null
            && castOther.getDReturn() != null && this.getDReturn().equals(castOther.getDReturn())))
        && ((this.getDCtr() == castOther.getDCtr()) || (this.getDCtr() != null && castOther.getDCtr() != null
            && this.getDCtr().equals(castOther.getDCtr())))
        && ((this.getDRecdat() == castOther.getDRecdat()) || (this.getDRecdat() != null
            && castOther.getDRecdat() != null && this.getDRecdat().equals(castOther.getDRecdat())))
        && ((this.getDRectime() == castOther.getDRectime()) || (this.getDRectime() != null
            && castOther.getDRectime() != null && this.getDRectime().equals(castOther.getDRectime())));
}

public int hashCode()
{
    int result = 17;

    result = 37 * result + (getDJon() == null ? 0 : this.getDJon().hashCode());
    result = 37 * result + (getDReturn() == null ? 0 : this.getDReturn().hashCode());
    result = 37 * result + (getDCtr() == null ? 0 : this.getDCtr().hashCode());
    result = 37 * result + (getDRecdat() == null ? 0 : this.getDRecdat().hashCode());
    result = 37 * result + (getDRectime() == null ? 0 : this.getDRectime().hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

}

Here is the curl:

> curl --libcurl C:\Development\test.log -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"DJon\":\"a\",\"DReturn\":\"a\",\"DCtr\":1,\"DRecdat\":\"a\",\"DRectime\":\"a\"}" http://localhost:8080/taaDaoWS/deleteJonTblGet

The controller method is executed but the deleteJonTblId object has all null values.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting:  I changed the json column names to lowercase and it began to work.